# Double for loop to extract data from several urls

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from a website to write them on an excel file to be worked on. I have a main url scheme and I have to change the "year" and the "reference number" accordingly:

http://calcio-seriea.net/presenze/"year"/"reference number"/

I already tried to write a part of the code but I have one issue. First of all, I should keep the year the same while the reference number takes every number of an interval of 18. Then the year increases of 1, and the reference number take again every number of an interval of 18. I try to give an example:

```
Y = 1998 RN = [1142:1159];
Y = 1999 RN = [1160:1177];
Y = 2000 RN = [1178:1195];
Y = … RN = …
```

Then from year 2004 the interval becomes of 20, so

```
Y = 2004 RN = [1250:1269];
Y = 2005 RN = [1270:1289];
```

Till year = 2019 included.

This is the code I could make so far:

```
import pandas as pd

year = str(1998)

all_items = []

for i in range(1142, 1159):
    pattern = "http://calcio-seriea.net/presenze/" + year + "/" + str(i) + "/"

    df = pd.read_html(pattern)[6]

    all_items.append(df)

pd.DataFrame(all_items).to_csv(r"C:\Users\glcve\Desktop\data.csv", index = False, header = False)

print("Done!")
```

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: This should be two separate and very specific questions. The first should be about only string-formatting, and the second is how to correctly input the retrieved data into a DataFrame.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought it would be spam to ask two questions in two different topics. I'd change then

Comment: You should maybe ask one question at a time, so that you can give feedback to the questions in the comments or answers with more focus.

Comment: all you need to do is `pd.concat(all_items)` before you write to csv.

Comment: HampusLarsson I edited the question
Datanovice Thanks i already checked and it works! Really stupid question on my side ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that's missing is a `pd.concat` from your function, however as you're calling the same method over and over, lets write a function so you can keep your code dry.

```
def create_html_df(base_url, year,range_nums = ()):
    """
    Returns a dataframe from a url/html table
    base_url : the url to target
    year : the target year.
    range_nums = the range of numbers i.e (1,50)

   """
    start, stop = range_nums
    url_pat = [f"{base_url}/{year}/{i}" for i in range(start,stop)]
    dfs = []
    for each_url in url_pat:
        df = pd.read_html(each_url)[6]
        dfs.append(df)

    return pd.concat(dfs)
```

---

```
final_df = create_html_df(base_url = "http://calcio-seriea.net/presenze/",
               year = 1998,
               range_nums = (1142, 1159))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The only thing is that i would like to add all the data on the same variable all_items.
This means that the data from year = 1998 range num (1142, 1159) are concatenated with year = 1999 range num (1160, 1177) and so on

Comment: then you can add an outer loop to the function and iterate over your years, feel free to edit and play with it your self :) @Gianluca

Comment: I tried this solution but i get an error on the range_nums _in <module>
    range_nums = (int(1142+18*(y-1998)), int(1142+18*(y-1998))))_. If you could give a glance it would be of great help
`year = range(1998, 2004)
final_dfs = []
for y in year:
    final_df = create_html_df(base_url = "http://calcio-seriea.net/presenze/",
               year = y,
               range_nums = (int(1142+18*(y-1998)), int(1142+18*(y-1998))))
    final_dfs.append(final_df)`